# Issues with running plasma-modeling sample script

Tags: python, openmc-plasma-source

I am currently trying to use some modeling software for a project I have to do for school. I am currently using Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and VSCode as my IDE.

I am trying to use a library called [openmc-plasma-source](https://github.com/fusion-energy/openmc-plasma-source) to model a plasma in a tokamak. For this I installed openmc as well, and followed the [install from source](https://docs.openmc.org/en/stable/quickinstall.html) tutorials for Ubuntu. I copied the [sample code found for a tokamak](https://github.com/fusion-energy/openmc-plasma-source/blob/main/examples/tokamak_source_example.py) from their repo into a file and hit run. When I try and run the script from either my IDE or straight from terminal, I am met with this error:

```
                                 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                                     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                 ###############      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                ##################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                ###################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                ####################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                #####################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                ######################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                #######################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                 #######################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                 ######################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                  ####################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                    #################     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                     ###############     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                       ############     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                          ########     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                                      %%%%%%%%%%%

                 | The OpenMC Monte Carlo Code
       Copyright | 2011-2022 MIT, UChicago Argonne LLC, and contributors
         License | https://docs.openmc.org/en/latest/license.html
         Version | 0.13.0
        Git SHA1 | cff247e35785e7236d67ccf64a3401f0fc50a469
       Date/Time | 2022-03-06 19:33:51   OpenMP Threads | 8


Reading settings XML file...  ERROR: No cross_sections.xml file was 
specified in materials.xml or in the OPENMC_CROSS_SECTIONS environment 
variable. OpenMC needs such a file to identify where to find data 
libraries. Please consult the user's guide at https://docs.openmc.org/ 
for information on how to set up data libraries. 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "plasma.py", line 64, in <module>
    model.run()   
File "/home/agilan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmc/model/model.py", line 580, in run
    openmc.run(particles, threads, geometry_debug, restart_file,   
File "/home/agilan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmc/executor.py", line 276, in run
    _run(args, output, cwd)   
File "/home/agilan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmc/executor.py", line 116, in _run
    raise RuntimeError(error_msg) RuntimeError: 

No cross_sections.xml file was specified in materials.xml or in the 
OPENMC_CROSS_SECTIONS environment variable. OpenMC needs such a file to
identify where to find data libraries. Please consult the user's guide 
at https://docs.openmc.org/ for information on how to set up data 
libraries.
```

Sorry if this is a dumb mistake, but I'm still a beginner. Could anybody help or tell me what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It looks like OpenMC requires some configuration settings after you install. [Section 3](https://docs.openmc.org/en/stable/usersguide/cross_sections.html) of their user guide seems to address this missing cross section environment variable that is causing your error.

Comment: Just as a heads up, there is some ongoing discussion about limiting the participation of unregistered users on the site: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317/does-the-matter-modeling-community-want-to-ban-unregistered-users-from-asking-qu. If you register your account, you won't have to worry if any limits are put in place for unregistered accounts.